# stop jquery to run server side code on validation fail

Tags: php, jquery

Sorry for the very basic question but i am asking here after trying to search alot.

Basically i am doing client side validation its running the half code but it is running the php code also even if it fails.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formValidation(){
        if($("#inputCname").val() == ''){
            alert("Category missing");
            ($this).css("border-color","red");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
</script>
```

Below i am calling the function. Please note that i have already tried with onclick event on the submit button still not working.

```
<form class="form form-search" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="formValidation();">
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: do you have errors being thrown in console that prevent this code running?

Comment: `($this)` should be `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a return to the **onsubmit** to stop the submission

```
<form class="form form-search" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
```

EDIT
There's also a problem in your JS function

```
$("#inputCname").css("border-color","red");
```

Comment: Its still not working..It shows alert and then submit the forms

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this for every form element, use jquery validation, It will do it all for you. Also showing alert for every form element is not a good practice. It will solve your all problems with validation providing you more features.

You can download jquery validation and check out its documentation from following link.

Download link  http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Documentation to implement  http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/